# can anyone tell me what IAM role policy required for setup Jmeter on aws as a user

Tags: jmeter, amazon-iam, policy

can anyone tell me what IAM role policy required for setup Jmeter on aws as a user.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is a piece of software which user can [download from Internet](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and launch, you don't need to "setup" it at all.

The only pre-requisite is [JRE](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/jre) (or better [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit)) version 8+

More information: [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)

I cannot think of any suitable IAM policy, the user needs to be able to access the machine over RDP or SSH, it is not necessary even to have an AWS account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but iam setting up Jmeter on aws account as i have IAM usr account but i cannot find any correct policy it is failing due to less permission.